# Right align header not working

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to align my header to the right side but it is not going all the way to the right.

[image]

Here is a minimal example (I'm including my margins in case that is part of the problem? I honestly have no idea):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{header}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\textwidth=7in
\textheight=9.5in
\topmargin = -.25 in
\hoffset=-1in
\voffset=-0.5in
\parskip = 0.1in
\parindent = 0.0in

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage{showframe}` and you could see how wrong are your margins setup. Use `geometry` to setup margins.

Comment: @Sigur the geometry package was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: @a cast, Welcome! Use the search filed here on TEX.SE. There are many good examples.

Answer (score 5):

You should set `\pagestyle{fancy}` *after* having set the page parameters, because `fancyhdr` uses the current text width for preparing its headers and footers.

I recommend using `geometry`, though: probably

```
\usepackage[textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{header}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

is sufficient for your needs.

Above all, *never* set `\hoffset` and `\voffset`: they are thought for making corrections in case the output driver needs them.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens (at least on my side) when you set a different page geometry for the title page.

If, you set `pagestyle{fancy}` and all the header specifications already in the preamble, then the your header specification are for the default geometry. If you change your page geometry afterwards, all the header settings will be skewed. Therefore, I recommend a specifing in a `newcommand` and calling it when your page properties are set and done.